# How to convert PCollection<Row> to Integer in Dataflow Apache beam using Java

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, apache-beam, dataflow

Creating the pcollection

```
PCollection<Row> count = pt.apply(SqlTransform.query(Constants.total_count));
        PCollectionView<Long> outputCount = detail_count
                .apply("Row to long",
                        ParDo.of(new RowToLong())).apply(View.asSingleton());
```

Query

```
String total_count  = select sum(cast(col1 as INT)) as total_count from <table>
```

Converting RowToInteger method

```
public class RowToLong extends DoFn<Row, Integer> {
    public static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RowToLong.class.getName());    

    private PCollectionView<Integer> outputCount;      

    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(ProcessContext context) {    
        

        Integer total_count= Long.valueOf(context.element().getInt64("total_count"));          
          context.output(total_count);    
    }

}
```

error

> java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long

Comment: Same issue kindly suggest idea to resolve

Comment: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/dsls/sql/walkthrough/

Comment: Did you try to change you `DoFn<Row, Integer>` in `DoFn<Row, Long>`?

Comment: Try adding a cast before assigning to the Integer, e.g. Integer total_count = (int) Long.valueOf(...). This will of course truncate if your 64-bit long value doesn't fit in a 32-bit int.

Answer (score 3):

```
String total_count  = select sum(cast(col1 as bigint)) as total_count from <table>
Integer total_count = context.element().getInt64("total_count");
```